# How to batch rename Files, moving character to the end

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, rename, batch-rename

Having previously used batch files to rename files with success, I thought this would be possible, but I just cannot get it to work for this case.

I have the following files which I'd like to rename so that they are ordered correctly:

- `IMG_9963` - no change
- `IMG_E9963` should be renamed to `IMG_9963E`

So basically, if there is an E, it needs to be moved from where it is to the end of the file name. The rest of the file name should be unchanged.

There may be thousands of files to run through.

To complicate things, the filenames may already have been prefixed so the E may not always be the same place. The E will always be before the numbers though & will always be an E. So examples could be:

```
WorkIMG_9963
WorkIMG_E9963
AIMG_9963
AIMG_E9963
```

I've tried lots of different approaches, but coding is not my strength. I've only previously pre-fixed filenames etc. This is the kind of thing I was trying:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%j in (*) do (
set old_filename=%%j
set "new_filenameA=!old_filename:E=!"
set "new_filenameB=!new_filenameA!E"
ren "!old_filename!" "!new_filenameB!"
)
```

How can I automate this type of renaming task?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! We are a community of people that are interested in computers, not a free coding service. Please share what you already have done so that we can find the error, that way it is less work for us and a better suited answer for you.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Please provide a basic code and explain. If there is an E after the _ the E should be moved to the end of the filename is that it?

Comment: *The E may not always appear in the same place.* -- Examples? Is IMG_E9963 and IMG_99E63 possible? Is it always an "E"? Could it be another letter? Could there be multiple letters? If so, how would you handle them? Is 12345E and 123E45 possible? Would they need to be kept in order? Please consider [edit]ing your question to include these details and any other details that may be relevant.

Comment: @supermonkey the way you put it almost worked exept it moves the E to end of the extension of the filename and not to the end of the filename.

Comment: @Ricardo Bohner yes, it does seem that far off... i tried other approaches but that was the cloeset. Feels like there's a solution, but I just cannot see it.

Comment: @supermonkey: You can save only the filename to variable by using set NewName=%%~nj https://pastebin.com/raw/ftRhazUg (drag and drop the folder where the files are to the batch)

Comment: @Ricardo Bohner many thanks, that does add an E to the end, however it seemed to rename the file that didn't have an E (that should be unchanged) but did rename the file that did have an E (which should have that E moved to the end).

Comment: @supermonkey: try now it should not change files that don't have an E now: https://pastebin.com/raw/y1qmurnJ

Comment: @Ricardo Bohner Wow, that's perfect thanks. Just ran a quick test & worked well. I'll do a larger trial & advise back how it goes. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad you got this working (even though we never got the question reopened).  I'd also recommend considering a batch renaming tool for things like this, rather than writing script.  Several possible candidates come to mind, including the batch rename tool in Microsoft's [Windows PowerToys](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/install), or shareware apps [Total Commander](https://www.ghisler.com) or (my favorite) [Directory Opus](https://www.gpsoft.com.au).  This would be a regex rename from `(.*)_(E*)(\d+)$` to `\1_\3\2`. It can take a bit to learn, but regex is well worth it.

Comment: Explaining the above regex, btw -- It says "Anything" (`.*`) followed by an underscore, followed by an optional `E`, followed by a number.  Anything in parenthesis's is "stored" in order, so you then rename it to `\1` (the "anything"), followed by the `_`, followed by the numbers (`\3`), followed by the `E` (`\2`) if it was there.

Comment: Many thanks, I will look into this also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'm adding this as answer since the topic got reopened now:

```
@echo off

setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

if exist "%~1" (if not exist "%~1\" exit) else (exit)
pushd "%~1"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b "%~1"') do (
                                             set Name=%%~na
                                             set Name=!Name:E=!
                                             set "NewName=!Name!E%%~xa"
                                             if not "%%~na"=="!Name!" ren "%%a" "!NewName!"
                                            )
popd
```

Comment: Probably safer to replace `_E` with `_` (`set Name=!Name:_E=_!`) than just removing `E` (there could be one in the prefix)